# Mongodb , "JOIN" a nested object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to join the faults array

```json
{
  "_id": "99812930-37CE-456F-A9D9-837E9E3F712A",
  "faultsChanged": [
    {
      "_id": "7C628A46-7E80-4615-8B08-10C5E9A6B1D7",
      "faults": [
        "BF221A71-0217-42E7-B853-53112EDA9694",
        "E4A54172-7E93-49C4-840B-8E6116116979"
      ],
      "isDeleted": false,
      "partition": "indego",
      "sessionUuid": "A83CE9A1-7539-493F-8BA4-6FBE25B18B57",
      "source": "1",
      "timestamp": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1630603342700"
        }
      },
      "unmigratedNote": null,
      "uuid": "7C628A46-7E80-4615-8B08-10C5E9A6B1D7"
    }
  ] 
}
```

So that it gets replaced by a document from another collection `OOFaultEntry`.
New to the aggregation pipeline, I have tried

```js
{$lookup:{
  from: "OOFaultEntry",
  localField: 'faultsChanged.faults',
  foreignField: "_id",
  let:{faults:"$faultsChanged.faults"},
  pipeline:[],
  as:"faults"
}}
```

but this just created a key on the result and was not embedded inside of each respective `faultChanged` object
expected result
`OOFaultEntry` would be JOINED on _id . So ,it should look something like

```json
{
   "_id": "99812930-37CE-456F-A9D9-837E9E3F712A",
   "faultsChanged": [
       {
           "_id": "7C628A46-7E80-4615-8B08-10C5E9A6B1D7",
           "faults": [
               {
                   "_id": "BF221A71-0217-42E7-B853-53112EDA9694",
                   "some_key": "value"
               },
               {
                   "_id": "E4A54172-7E93-49C4-840B-8E6116116979",
                   "some_key": "value"
               }
           ],
           "isDeleted": false,
           "partition": "indego",
           "sessionUuid": "A83CE9A1-7539-493F-8BA4-6FBE25B18B57",
           "source": "1",
           "timestamp": {
               "$date": {
                   "$numberLong": "1630603342700"
               }
           },
           "unmigratedNote": null,
           "uuid": "7C628A46-7E80-4615-8B08-10C5E9A6B1D7"
       }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Likely because `faultsChanged.faults` resolved to array of array. You might want to `$in` in the sub-pipeline for matching

Comment: Could you elaborate on it ? not getting how to use `$in` ,that would be to check if it exists in array ,correct ?

Comment: Can you also provide some sample documents in collection `OOFaultEntry` and the expected output?

Comment: edited to reflect the expected result . The array of `faults` is the array of `_id` of documents in `OOFaultEntry` collection @ray

Comment: check if this helps = https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/lookup-match-from-key-inside-array-of-objects-in-foreign-collection/113773/2

Answer (score 0):

One way would be `$unwind` the `faultsChanged` array first. Perform the `$lookup` and regroup the results.

```js
db.Faults.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$faultsChanged"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "00FaultEntry",
      "localField": "faultsChanged.faults",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "faultsChanged.faults"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "faultsChanged": {
        $push: "$faultsChanged"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pgkDscnqBR_)